# Eclipse: why is a resource in the package explorer annotated with the suffix (1)?

Tags: eclipse

In the screenshot below of my Eclipse Package Explorer, why is the DateUtil.java resource annotated with a suffix of (1)? What does this mean?

[image: eclipse package explorer resource annotated with (1)]

Comment: Can you tell the version you are using and any plugins you have installed? My bet is that it's caused by some plugin. Could it be that `DateUtil.java` contains some marker in its code, like a `TODO`?

Comment: I assume you are using a git plugin (checked out `master`); If you do a git status, does it report something on `DateUtil.java` which might be represented by the `(1)`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip - you pointed me in the right direction. It is a FindBugs warning marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Findbugs bug count decorator.

Comment: Aha! As a reference, the unofficial FindBugs Eclipse plugin page: http://andrei.gmxhome.de/findbugs/index.html (3. Show SF project page analysis results)